# Thread issues with realm

Tags: android, multithreading, android-fragments, realm

I have a problem with my threads.

I have my fragment where I retrieve 2 realm objects. When I send these 2 objects to another fragment (dialog fragment), and try to connect them with another object I get the error: Realm access from incorrect thread, Realm objects can only be accessed on the threads where they were created.

How can I solve (workaround) this?

Comment: Well the error message is honestly quite specific. You shouldn't be accessing the Realm instance or managed Realm object from a different thread than where it was created. So you can solve it by not doing that.

Comment: The fragment of your code causing the issue may be really helpful for tracing the issue.

Comment: *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"*

Answer (score -1):

I found out that this answer solves my problem. ( not sure if its the correct way to do it )

```
youRealmObject = realm.copyFromRealm(youRealmObject);
```

[Android Realm - Accessing Realm Object from Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35492039/android-realm-accessing-realm-object-from-service)