# Java android Realm access from incorrect thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, realm

Hi I create a Realm on onCreate() next I want to in public `class CheckerThread extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Boolean>` in doInBackground store a date but I have a

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created.

onCreate I have this :

```
realm = RealmController.with(this).getRealm();
```

next in AsynTask I download a data and I want to save this , I want to do this in doInBackground , but when I do this I have :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm instance can only be closed on the thread it was created.
```

I do on doInBackground this but it doesn't help :

```
try {
                                    realm = RealmController.with(getApplication()).getRealm();
                                    RealmController.with(getApplication()).save(data);
                                }
                                finally {
                                    realm.close();
                                }
```

A RealmController ;

```
public class RealmController {

    private static RealmController instance;
    private final Realm realm;

    public RealmController(Application application) {
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    }

    public static RealmController with(Fragment fragment) {

        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new RealmController(fragment.getActivity().getApplication());
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public static RealmController with(Activity activity) {

        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new RealmController(activity.getApplication());
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public static RealmController with(Application application) {

        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new RealmController(application);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public static RealmController getInstance() {

        return instance;
    }

    public Realm getRealm() {

        return realm;
    }

    //Refresh the realm istance
    public void refresh() {

        realm.refresh();
    }
```

Comment: Don't access managed RealmObjects queried on the UI thread inside `doInBackground()` which runs on a background thread. Open and close the Realm instance with `try-finally` inside `doInBackground()` and requery your object based on its primary key.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce so how I can do this ?

Comment: Open and close the Realm instance with try-finally inside doInBackground() and requery your object based on its primary key.

Comment: I don't know your code so I can't really help beyond telling you what you need to do.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I edit my post

Comment: You literally just have to do what @EpicPandaForce said in the comments of the OP. Make a new Realm instance *inside* the AsyncTask, and close it once you're done reading/writing. It's okay to create a new Realm object **as long as you don't forget to close it**.

Comment: Judging by the looks of it `RealmController` is a class that holds several static helper functions for working with Realm, yes? And does it store the Realm instance in a class variable? Or is a new instance made and closed for every operation? The `RealmController` is the interesting class here.

Comment: @nbokmans I edit my post and put RealmController

Comment: Honestly this RealmController isn't doing very much except for applying the Singleton design (anti)pattern, which is actually causing the threading issue here. So unless you are using any of the features I would recommend just cutting it out and just doing `Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()` whenever you need a Realm instance. This article might be useful for you: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#controlling-the-lifecycle-of-realm-instances

Comment: @KrzysztofPokrywka [***STOP referring to the infohive Realm tutorial by Ravi Tamada***, that code is extremely **outdated** (uses Realm **0.82.2** even though **2.3.1** is out!), badly written, **shows poor practices**, and is just generally an atrocity! DO NOT USE THE RAVI TAMADA REALM TUTORIAL AS A GUIDE OR TUTORIAL OF ANY SORT. IT IS BAD.](https://medium.com/@Zhuinden/how-to-use-realm-for-android-like-a-champ-and-how-to-tell-if-youre-doing-it-wrong-ac4f66b7f149)

Comment: @nbokmans just make sure you also close them when you're on background threads

Comment: @KrzysztofPokrywka from the end of that article, this is a much better example code (I know because I wrote it): https://github.com/Zhuinden/realm-book-example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As also mentioned [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35492039/android-realm-accessing-realm-object-from-service/40294190#40294190), don't access managed RealmObjects queried on the UI thread inside `doInBackground()` which runs on a background thread. Open and close the Realm instance with `try-finally` inside `doInBackground()` and requery your object based on its primary key.

Also, throw out that `RealmController`, it is a pointless addition based on the badly-written Ravi Tamada infohive Realm tutorial, which tells you to use Realm 0.82.2 despite that version being 2 years old. It completely disregards the fact that Realm instances are thread-confined, and you'll run into `IllegalStateException` with it, just like you did now. Ravi Tamada got away with it because he executes all his write transactions on the UI thread, which is generally a bad idea.

Let me state in bold caps, ***THE INFOHIVE REALM TUTORIAL IS TERRIBLE AND PROMOTES BAD PRACTICES. DO NOT USE.***

You should refer to [**this repository**](https://github.com/Zhuinden/realm-book-example) for a proper Realm tutorial. But you can also check [**my profile**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2413303/epicpandaforce?tab=profile) for additional Realm-related resources.

Comment: Thanks for help !! :-)

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you are trying to access an object created on main thread. AsyncTask gives you a method that is onPostExecution(), from here you can access your realm object but not in doInBackground() method. In cas you want to access the object from doInBackground() then you can use Handler class. Docs is given in link below.[enter link description here](http://mrbool.com/how-to-implement-multi-threading-in-android-with-handler-class/28175)

Comment: This is an elaborate workaround. I suggest taking @EpicPandaForce's route